# Accept any class template in method arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have AnyClass and AnyMethod inside. What I want to do, is convert AnyClass<F> into AnyClass<T>.

```
template<typename T>
class AnyClass
{
public:
    static AnyClass<T> AnyMethod(AnyClass<F> obj);
}
```

For example:

```
AnyClass<long int> anyObject();
AnyClass<int> anyObject2 = AnyClass<int>::AnyMethod(anyObject);
```

I'm converting instance of AnyClass<long int> into AnyClass<int>. I already know how to do convert itself, but I don't know how to accept all types of class in AnyMethod.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to template the function as well:

```
template<typename F>
static AnyClass<T> AnyMethod(AnyClass<F> obj);
```

(You might want to pass `obj` as const reference though.)

Comment: Alan is correct. What worries me is that you are writing to accept all types of class. To do this properly, you have to specialize a member function, rather than mixing templates and RTTI

Answer (score 1):

[Alan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23030054/2644390) is fine, but for this job I think a constructor is more appropriate than a static method:

```
template<typename T>
class AnyClass
{
public:
    template<typename F>
    AnyClass(AnyClass<F> obj);
}
```

Comment: But how about method definition? Ok, we have a declaration, but I don't know how to define it. `template<typename T, F>` doesn't work

Comment: @stil This depends entirely on how `AnyClass` is defined, what it contains, and what you want to do. This is a copy constructor, so normally should be `AnyClass(const AnyClass<F>& obj)` (and there should also be a move constructor `AnyClass(AnyClass<F>&& obj)`. With the empty class you have now, the constructors would be empty as well: `{ }`.